# por que sale el error "Dont know how to iterate over splied items" al crear un foreach en un jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, spring, servlets, jstl

Tengo el siguiente método en mi controlador y lo que hace es obtener las rutas a las que tiene derecho un usuario a través de su clave, por eso se manda a llamar al método **obtenerMenus** esas rutas que me regresa las quiero pintar en mi jsp a través de hipervinculos con imágenes para que parezcan como submenus, para ello uso el objeto **model**

```
@GetMapping(value="/admin/menu", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView ejecutarMenu(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView(PANTALLA_NAVEGACION);
        Respuesta respuesta = new Respuesta();
        Usuario user = new Usuario();
        user.setClave(Constants.CLAVE);

        List<Menu> menu = servicio.obtenerMenus("001")
        for(Menu menuPagina: menu){
            model.addAttribute("rutas", menuPagina);
        }
        try{
            respuesta.setFlujo(Constants.INT_TRES);
        }catch(IOException e){
            logger.error("IOException", e);
            respuesta = servicioAdmin.obtenerRespuesta(null, ErrorEnum.EXCEPCION);
        }
        modelView = utileria.agregarRespuestaModel(modelView, respuesta);
        return model;

    }
```

Y en el jsp tengo el forEach para que si el servicio me regresa 3 rutas, pinte tres hipervínculos, o quizá solo 1.

```
<section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class=""slick-carousel>
            <c:forEach var="ruta" items="${rutas}">
                <a href="${ruta.chRuta}" class="CarrouselMenu_ThumbContainer">
                    <div class="Icon">
                        <img class="IconImgMenu" src="../webResources/img/alta.png" alt="icon_menu">
                    </div>
                    <div class="CarrouselMenu_Title"> ALTA</div>
                </a>
            </c:forEach>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Esta es mi entidad Menu:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TC_MENU")
public class Menu implments Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name ="CV_MENU")
private String cvMenu;

@Id
@Column(name ="CV_MENU_PAG")
private String cvMenuPag;


@Column(name ="CV_PAGINA")
private String cvPagina;


@Column(name ="CH_RUTA")
private String chRuta;


@Column(name ="CH_DESC_PAG")
private String chDescPagina;


}
```

El servicio actualmente me regresa una lista con dos registros, y me sale el error:

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to Iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach>

mal en el forEach?

Comment: En  el `ejecutarMenu` del controller estas pisando el mismo atributo haciendo varias veces el add en el `for`. Deberías de pasarle en el atributo el `ArrayList` entero e iterar en el jsp como estas haciendo. `model.addAttribute("rutas", menu);`

Comment: @x3k_js gracias, eres un crack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pongo como respuesta, aun que sea algo muy especifico para este caso.

Tu error es el siguiente, con el siguiente `for` estas pisando con cada iteración el atributo del `model` por lo que cuando llega al `JSP` llega 1 ruta/menu en vez de un conjunto de estos:

```
List<Menu> menu = servicio.obtenerMenus("001")
for(Menu menuPagina: menu){
    model.addAttribute("rutas", menuPagina);
}
```

Para arreglarlo tienes que pasar la lista entera en el atributo:

```
List<Menu> menu = servicio.obtenerMenus("001")
model.addAttribute("rutas", menu);
```

e iteras como ya estas haciendo:

```
<c:forEach var="ruta" items="${rutas}">
    <a href="${ruta.chRuta}" class="CarrouselMenu_ThumbContainer">
        <div class="Icon">
            <img class="IconImgMenu" src="../webResources/img/alta.png" alt="icon_menu">
        </div>
        <div class="CarrouselMenu_Title"> ALTA</div>
    </a>
</c:forEach>
```